# Wicket project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wicket

I was trying to configure wicket with Eclipse on Ubuntu. I used [this guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Windows+Guide+to+Installing+Wicket+on+Eclipse+with+Maven)
So I generated some commands in quickstart tab, paste it into the terminal new maven project was created. Then I ran *mvn eclipse:eclipse* command. I imported generated project into Eclipse and that`s where my problems started. In project run configurations there was an error in **m2** variable, where it references to **wicket-core** directory. I have 2 directories in **wicket-core**: **7.5.0-SNAPSHOT** and **7.6.0**. By default M2_REPO variable references to **7.5.0-SNAPSHOT** directory containing **wicket-core-7.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.lastUpdated**, but it is an illegal zip file, so I renamed it to **wicket-core-7.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**.
So when I ran Start class in /src/test/java I get **Error: Could not find or load main class com.calculator.Start**
I can not figure out whether it is wicket configuration problem or it is versions compliance problem?
I would be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you face a bug in the quickstart for 7.6.0. Wrongly it uses 7.5.0-SNAPSHOT in pom.xml. You will have to fix the version in a text editor and regenerate the Eclipse project. This is fixed in 7.7.0.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But where exactly should I fix the version?

Comment: In pom.xml file change 7.5.0-SNAPSHOT with 7.6.0